# Php login system with salted hashes unable to match again from database

Tags: php, hash, mysqli, php-password-hash

My first attempt at php and i'm working with password_compat since the server runs a version of php <5.5 .

I have a set of user details which i've stored into the databse automatically. Each user has a unique salt generated from `$random_salt = mcrypt_create_iv(24, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);` and i've tried to store it into the database as a blob and along that I store my hashed password with the following

```
$options = array('cost' => 8, 'salt' => $random_salt); 
$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
```

To verify I query the database, get my match and pass the salt attribute into a variable $salt, and get the stored hashed password. Finally using the following

```
$options = array('cost' => 8, 'salt' => $salt); 
$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
$intVar = (int) password_verify($password, $db_password);
```

my results so far on a just one of the logins is a no match.

Where am I going wrong? Is it the database attribute datatype for the salt? my use of the password_hash?

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered that the carriage return "\r" still existed at the end of my passwords when the automatically went into the database, read in via a tab delimited file. The program was right the whole time. My password was wrong by a "\r" .

Comment: Good on you (and an upvote) for solving this, and for posting the solution.